# Is there a way to avoid syntax colouring in eclipse for Print Statements?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have applied some syntax colouring in Eclipse. `System.out.println` also has different colours based on class (System), method (println) etc. I was thinking is there a way to have say just one colour for System.out.println() so it is easier to read? I would like different colours for other statements but just not for System.out.println().

Is it possible?

[image]

`System.out.println("HI")` has colours dark purple, blue, brown. Is there a way this whole statement can be allocated just ONE colour? This will make it easier for me to read. I want the others to stay as they are.

I don't know if such a tool exist where you can only change colours of certain statements, but it would be cool to have one!

Comment: You should find something in preferences?

Comment: I've tried many settings, but if there is, I can't find it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Isn't it under Run/Debug -> Console?

Comment: Noo, I want the colour of 'System.out.println()' to be different in the editor. Since, I have different colours for classes, the word 'System' changes to that colour. I want a way in which the syntax colouring doesnt affect print statements.

Comment: Don't know if it is just me, but I'm confused. Could you post an image that shows what the situation currently is and how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: I have attached an image of what I want. It is not a big problem, but just something that will make things easier to read for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to `Windows-> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring` (This can be also launched by searching "Syntax Coloring" in `Windows -> Preferences`)

Once the Syntax Coloring dialog is loaded it should look like below

[image]

Now select, **Classes** (which is `System`) --> Enable it and choose any color you want (I have chosen Black)
select, **Static Fields** (which is `out`) --> Enable it and choose any color and font texture you want
and then select **Static Method Invocation** ( corresponds to `println`) --> Enable it and choose color

Enabling each will change the default colors assigned for them, and allow us to choose  custom coloring. Here's the outcome after changing (You can even change the color of 'keywords' and 'text literals'

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but I already know this. I used syntax colour to  change the colours in my screenshot. My question is different. You know how System, out and println are different expressions.. Is there a way to treat them as one single expression with one colour? How you have green for all comments, is it possible to have green for system.out.println? i dont want to change colours of classes, static fields and methods to one colour because i need them for other statements. It is only for this print statement that I want a single colour. Although I don't think something like that exists..